Import the same component into both Parent and Child components?
Using react we import children components from the parent component. As an example, our parent imports the AWS-SDK package. The child also uses this package. Does the child inherit the AWS-SDK package or do we need to import the same package into the child?
Seems less than straight forward and I am getting mixed results. What is the best practice?

This is very dependent on the specific use case on how you want to handle this in terms of best practices but the child will NOT inherit the import. Anywhere you need it, it will need to be imported. Typically in situations with things such as the AWS-SDK people tend to create service files and util files to handle data fetching and handling of lambdas and such to make it easier. This is also true with creating custom hooks if needed and a lot of other different use cases! Let me know if there is anything specific you want me to expand on.

that sums up my suspicions on the matter. I was hoping to avoid redundancies the children could inherit those imports from the parent but that sounds like wishful thinking.

Yeah, React isn’t that kind to us unfortunately. The use of service files and such can help tho and usually what I go with, having a function to fetch something or whatever you want to do and importing that instead of the entire package or whatever. Same redundancy will eventually happen tho unfortunately lol
